# Number to date conversion

Tags: sql, oracle, date, to-char

I have the below Table. Is it possible to turn the Month column into a date?

```
ID    Month
 1    201805
```

Expected Results:

```
Id  Month    Date
1   201805   5/1/2018
```

Comment: 201805 * 100 + 1 = 20180501 --> this can be converted to a date quite easily, as it is already in ISO format.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, what benefit does that give? After that arithmetic it's still a number, not a date. To convert to date you still have to call `to_date` anyway, and you don't need arithmetic to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use [`to_date()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html) with a suitable format mask, e.g. with a fixed value as a demo:

```
select to_date(to_char(201805), 'YYYYMM') from dual;

TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(201
-------------------
2018-05-01 00:00:00
```

You don't need to explicitly add a day number to the value (as @HoneyBadger showed, or by concatenating after converting to a string), because [it will default to the first of the month](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-4D95F6B2-8F28-458A-820D-6C05F848CA23) anyway.

So you would need to do something like

```
to_date(to_char(month), 'YYYYMM')
```

The `to_char()` part could be skipped as the number would be implicitly converted to a string anyway, but it's more complete to include it.

---

It isn't clear if you intend to do this as part of a query (maybe in a view) or want to modify the table; if the latter then you could use a virtual column to avoid duplicating data and having to maintain the converted value if the month changes.